# In Unity3d test scripts, how do I call a static function from another class?

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nunit

I have two files in a Unity3d project.  One is a test script that runs in edit mode.  The other is a single class with static functions that I'd like to call from the test scripts.

here's my test script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections;

public class NewTestScript 
{

    [Test]
    public void TestAnotherStaticFunction() 
    {
        int a = NewBehaviourScript.FunctionUnderTest(1);
        int b = 1;

        // Use the Assert class to test conditions.
        Assert.IsTrue(a == b);
    }
}
```

here's my function under test:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// the stupidest function in the world, 
    /// used to verify tests.
    /// </summary>
    public static int FunctionUnderTest(int a)
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

This gives me the error from the Unity compiler (I'm not building outside of Unity):

*Assets/TestS/NewTestScript.cs(12,17): error CS0103: The name `NewBehaviourScript' does not exist in the current context*

These are running in edit-mode.

I've tried adding and removing the *SuperTestNameSpace* namespace from the function under test and the calling code.

I've attempted adding/removing files from the *.asmdef* file that was autogenerated by unity, although this usually leads to other compile errors.

My previous unit test experience is largely in Visual Studio or VSCode,  and I'm trying to get my unity3d test experience to match my prior test environment experiences.

Is there a fundamentally limited functionality in the edit-mode tests, or am I missing something stupid?

Further elaboration on the assemblies involved.  It looks like there are two assemblies at play here:  **Assembly-CSharp.dll** contains my code under test and **TestS.dll** contains my testing code.  I believe my questions boils down to: how do I add a reference from the TestS.dll assembly to the **Assembly-CSharp.dll**.  I'd know how to do this in Visual Studio (either via the context menu in VS or directly editing the csproj file), however I don't see how to do it in Unity3d.  Any edit I make to the csproj file is frequently overwritten by unity, and while there is a 'references' section in the inspector (see picture) I can't add **Assembly-CSharp.dll** as a reference.

[These are the inspector settings for TestS.asmdef.  While there's an option to add references, I can't add a reference to Assembly-CSharp.dll, which is where my code-under-test lives.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBnen.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  There were two things going on:

1. Editor tests need to be underneath a folder called editor.  It's really annoying that the unity editor doesn't do this for you.
2. You need to have an assembly definition for the code under test *and* add a reference from the test code to the newly created assembly definition.  This *must* be done in the Unity editor UI.

by default, unity adds your script code to an assembly called **Assembly-CSharp.dll**, and, for reasons unknown, this assembly isn't referenced by my edit mode test code.  I'm not sure if this is a bug in Unity or if it's by design, but explicitly creating and referencing the assembly definition has cleared things up.

Comment: This helped me a lot, and for point #2, in order to create an assembly definition, here's the page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is currently you are trying to call the

```c#
NewBehaviourScript(1);
```

constructor which does not exist...

instead of the  method

```c#
using SuperTestNameSpace;

//...

NewBehaviourScript.FunctionUnderTest(1);
```

or alternatively with the namespace in the call directly

```c#
SuperTestNameSpace.NewBehaviourScript.FunctionUnderTest(1);
```

---

Also make sure the filename matches exactly the class name. So in your case it should be

```c#
NewBehaviourScript.cs
```

Note that the `.cs` is not printed by Unity in the `Project` view so there it should say `NewBehaviourScript`.

---

Why does it not compile with the `using SuperTestNameSpace;`? What is the error?

If that exception

> Assets/TestS/NewTestScript.cs(14,17): error CS0103: The name `NewBehaviourScript' does not exist in the current context

is only shown in VisualStudio but the script compiling fine in Unity especially after adding a new script it helps to simply close and restart VS.

In some cases it also helps to close Unity and VS, remove all files and folders except `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` (and if you are under version control anything that belongs to it like e.g. `.git`, `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes` etc) in particular delete the `Library`, `.vs` folder and all `.csproj` and `.sln` files.

Than open Unity again and let it recompile everything.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct in that I wasn't calling the static function with proper syntax.  However, I'm still receiving a similar error on the script.  *NewBehaviourScript* still isn't recognized as a valid namespace. I've reworded the original question and updated the error message that I'm receiving from Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file that contains your NewBehaviourScript class **IS NOT** inside an Editor folder.

Move both the scripts in the Assets (root) folder and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I've confirmed that it's NOT inside an editor folder.  The folder structure is:


`\Assets\Scenes\NewBehaviourScript.cs
 \Assets\TestS\NewTestScript.cs
 \Assets\TestS\TestS.asmdef`